# PostgreSQL: drop fraction of second from interval

Tags: postgresql, time, intervals

My query:

```
SELECT AVG(time_out - time_in) from time_table
```

Result:

```
3 days 17:21:21.062313
```

The problem is, the computed average also has the fractional part of a second .062313, which I don't need, so I must drop it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`date_trunc` should do this:

```
SELECT date_trunc('second', avg(time_out - time_in))
FROM time_table
```

Comment: Great :-) I faild to quote second and discarded date_trunc as a solution. +1

Comment: Yes, it's not obvious that date_trunc() also works on intervals.

Comment: Shouldn't this be date_trunc('second', avg(time_out - time_in)) ?

Comment: Daniel is right... switching avg and date_trunc gives the correct result

Comment: I changed my example to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (AVG(time_out - time_in))::INTERVAL(0) FROM time_table;
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(time_out - time_in) AS INTERVAL(0)) FROM time_table;
```

Comment: I tried it and it works, but don't understand the logic - what does the (0) following INTERVAL do?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html, note the "precision" for the various types (time, timestamp, interval).